# Mitzva of Tzedaka for Pikuach Nefesh

Tags: money, tzedakah-charity, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Let's say one has a relative/parent who needs a life saving operation but does not have the financial means to pay for it or even get a loan, is one required to sell his property to help them?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about doing this qua kibbud av va'eim, or is that just an extra factor to the general question?

Comment: yes, along with kibud av otherwise I dont think one is required to do this even if no one else can help them. If you have a source against this, please let me know

Comment: Well, Rama rules (YD 240:5) that you can't be forced to give more of your money towards Kibbud Av than you would to Tzedaka. So we're back to the standard question.

Answer (score -2):

The passuk says "Tzedaka Tatzil Mimavess" (Mishlei 10:2) so while it may not be a chiyuv according Halacha, it certainly would be a legit segula to save them.

Answer (score -2):

Lo saamod al dam reechah is not docheh pikuach nephesh, so if it would disrupt your marriage for example to sell your house you need not do so to facilitate the operation.